# Twilio Autopilot Handof with memory for on call conversation

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have an [twilio autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-build-a-chatbot) similar to appointment schedule sample in `twilio`, I want it to have a memory before its even initiated, I have a B2C service, where I provide the platform to connect with their customers. Now each business offers different service so I want to be able to identify whose call my bot is attending and respond to the person based on that information.

Right now I have hardcoded  business ID, but I want businesses to be able to handover to the bot with their business ID, I have read the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off#6-build-agent-hand-off) but it doesn't say how to handle call redirect as my **Bot** would be handling calls only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this with [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard)!

"Inbound Context lets you add data to the Autopilot Memory before starting a dialogue with the bot. In a Studio flow, it allows you to pass Flow variables created by other widgets in your flow seamlessly into Autopilot to be used in bot conversations. You can then parse these variables directly from the Memory JSON included in Autopilot's request to your application" ([more info here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/studio#using-inbound-context-with-studio)):

-`Memory.CarMake`

-`Memory.CarModel`

[image]

You could alternatively use a URL like this one to pass Inbound Context with `Memory` where any message sent to a bot with this URL will insert `CarModel`, `CarMake`, and `CarYear` into the Autopilot Memory.
`https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/<ACCOUNT_SID>/<ASSISTANT_SID>/twilio-messaging?Memory={"CarModel":"Diablo","CarMake":"Lamborghini","CarYear":"2019"}`
That URL would go for a SMS bot and go in where you place the webhook URL for your Twilio phone number, but you could similarly modify it for [WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/whatsapp#autopilot-url-parameters) (*https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1///twilio-messaging/whatsapp?Memory={"CarModel":"Diablo","CarMake":"Lamborghini","CarYear":"2019"}*), Voice, [Custom Channels](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/custom-channel#autopilot-url-parameters) (*https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1///custom/{YourCustomChannelName}?Memory={"CarModel":"Diablo","CarMake":"Lamborghini","CarYear":"2019"}*) etc.

[TwiML for voice would look like this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/voice#autopilot-parameters):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Connect action="https://www.example.com/autopilot">
    <Autopilot Memory={"CarModel":"Diablo","CarMake":"Lamborghini","CarYear":"2019"}>UAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Autopilot>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

Let me know if this helps at all!:D

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but the problem is memory is dynamic.

Comment: You can dynamically insert variables into the TwiML!

Comment: I just did that with my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize Inbound Context, as detailed below.

Inbound Context
https://www.twilio.com/changelog/inbound-context

> Inbound Context lets you add data to the Autopilot Memory before
>   starting a dialogue with the bot. It can help you make the bot
>   experience more personalized and contextual by making information like
>   names, purchase histories, account numbers etc. stored in third-party
>   systems available directly in the bot conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to handle it, and it may not be the best way, but its really helpful for me.
So what I have done is I created an API that responds back with `Twml` 
Similar to [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/voice#autopilot-parameters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Connect action="https://www.example.com/autopilot">
    <Autopilot Memory={"CarModel":"Diablo","CarMake":"Lamborghini","CarYear":"2019"}>UAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Autopilot>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

Now I purchased number and set its webhook URL to the API I created, within that API, I can pass parameter and then create memory with those params

[image]

Here is my API handler in Nodejs:

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse
const voice = (req, res, next) => {

  const response = new VoiceResponse()
  const connect = response.connect()
  connect.autopilot({
    TargetTask: 'greeting',
    Memory: `{"companyId": "${req.params.id}"}`
  },
  process.env.AUTOPILOT_SID)

  res.type('text/xml')
  res.send(response.toString())
}
```

I hope this helps somebody who is looking to create dynamic memory based on different numbers, or to create a bot that works for multi-tenant platform